# What's wrong with my Visual Studio screen?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]

P.S. I am using a MAC but no clue how I suddenly ended up with this blue screen. Cant type nor select text here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to fix this is to go to file and reset factory settings to default.
It will work.